# New iPhone 8 asking for App Store password for someone else's account

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-id

I have an iPhone 8 that was set up from an iPhone 7 backup.

Every few minutes I get a popup asking for an App Store password, except the account it's specifying is an account that belongs to a family member.

Similar questions say that this can happen when an app was installed using a different App Store ID. So to fix this, I uninstalled every installed app.

I'm still getting the popup. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So to make sure, the *only* apps installed are stock iOS apps? (And if that's the case, why not erase it completely and start anew, not from a backup?)

Comment: Have you tried having them sign in to your phone?

Comment: @Sirens I would, they're not available to do so

Answer (score 1):

Head into Settings > iTunes & App Stores and at the top you should see that your iPhone is logged in with your family member's Apple ID.

Click on the Apple ID, then tap on Sign Out and then login with your Apple ID.

Comment: My Apple ID is already there.

Comment: What exactly does the pop-up say?

Comment: **Sign In To iTunes Store** - Enter the password for your Apple ID -
someoneelse@gmail.com - Password:

Comment: Ok this should fix the problem, open the App Store, tap on the profile icon from the top right corner and then tap on Sign Out

Comment: Tried that too, no dice.

Comment: That’s all the possible solutions I got, did u restart your phone after signing out on the App Store?